# Selenium Python only taking information from 32 out of 100 elements

Tags: python, selenium

I'm scraping data from a dynamic page which the element id's change as you scroll, I have it set to scroll down until it loads the last element and then the body of the page zooms out so all 100 elements are visible.

I then have 100 of these lines to collect the required data:

```
store1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                             "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/ia-dataview/krn-data-view-platform/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div").text

department1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                  "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/ia-dataview/krn-data-view-platform/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div").text

job1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                           "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/ia-dataview/krn-data-view-platform/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div").text

cost1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                            "/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div/ia-dataview/krn-data-view-platform/div/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div").text
```

I have the numbers changed that need to be up to 100 and it only collects the first 32 then stops. If I leave the chrome webdriver open and search the elements all 100 are visible so I'm not sure why it isn't collecting them all.

If anyone has any ideas that would be amazing!

A little edit, I've tried using some explicit waits and it seems when I use presence_of_element_located with the last element I need it goes through but only gets the text out of the first 32, if I use visibility_of_element_located it times out.

Comment: Would be great if you could share website as well. But anyways some websites use Javascript to show only those results in the HTML which are currently being viewed at. Basically it hides the results which are above or below. Like Twitter does.
Can you see any changes in the HTML as you scroll down the page?

Comment: It's a work related website behind a login so I unfortunately can't share it, it does use javascript and elements do change while scrolling but when I scroll to bottom to load them all and then zoom the page out all elements are visible in HTML.

Comment: Right. then I find it strange that the all elements are visible in html but not retrievable by the selenium query. can you use BeautifulSoup to see if it resolves your issue? And if that also fails then you would have to extract elements while scrolling down (i did the same with Twitter). then filter the duplicates at the end.